# SugarCRM - very SIMPLE Logic Hook executed with delay

Tags: hook, sugarcrm

i have very, very simple logic hook- I am still learning and I am confused at the start.
I turn on Developer mode.

I already have field "FIRST_NAME" in Contacts module.
I Created my field "MY_FIELD" also in COntacts module.

In logic_hooks.php file I added

```
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array();
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'Value from one field to another', 'custom/modules/Contacts/my.php', 'User_hook','copy');
```

In my.php file I added

```
class User_hook {

    function copy(&$bean, $event, $arguments)
    {

    $bean->my_field_c  = $bean->fetched_row['first_name']. " - additional text";
    }

}
```

So when I entered in First_Name value "First" I am getting in My field value "-additional text" but I should get "First- additional text."
If I go to Edit View and enter in First name field "Second" I am getting in My field value "First - additional text" but I should get "Second - additional text".
If I enetein Edit View "Third" I am getting in My field "Third - addiitional text" but I should get "Third - additional text".

So obviously my logic hook is executed with delay in one iteration- why and how to change it? This is my first hook so I am not so experience. Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$bean->fetched_row['first_name'] will return the value of the field BEFORE you change it.  You'd use this to see what the value of first_name was before the user changed it on the form.

Try using

```
class User_hook {

    function copy(&$bean, $event, $arguments)
    {

    $bean->my_field_c  = $bean->first_name. " - additional text";
    }

}
```

Comment: yes! this is working great thank you. I wish I could give you more thanh one up. May I ask you please if you have maybe some additional documentation for these and similar rules when working when Logic Hooks? On example for this methods fetched row, working with before save and other functions etc... I have some cook book, Developer guide (but mostly for web services) I am trying to find some good documentation for logic hooks but I am not succesful in it? I will be very thankful if you can share something with me (links or on email)..Thank you and all the best!!!

Comment: See the developer blog also for some helpful examples... http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/?s=logic+hooks